# How do you detect if a browser supports a JavaScript tiggered click on an input[type="file"]?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

There are a decent amount of older browsers that do not allow a triggered click event on file inputs due to security concerns (IE 7 / 8 and some older versions of Firefox, Safari, and Opera).  I'd like to know a reliable way to detect if a triggered click fails in such an instance.

The goal is to use a styled button / a:link to trigger the event.  The file input itself can be `opacity:0` or `visibility:hidden`.  Does not need to be `display:none`.

Comment: Last time I checked these would support a `.click()` as long as the element is *accessible* and resulting from user interaction.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté not in Chrome < 5 for example

Comment: @Esailija not sure if serious. `:P` On topic, here's an example that works in IE8 and latest Opera/Safari for Windows http://jsfiddle.net/XwPwu/show/

Comment: the % of people that use Chrome < 12 is like 0.4%

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I am serious :P Could be Windows Safari 5 too IIRC. But the Chrome < 5 is true story :(

Comment: @Esailija I meant, supporting old versions of IE is one thing, but Chrome.. You have go through Chrome's deep web of settings to find the disable auto-update option, and there's close to no reason to not updade it. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yeah I just mentioned it for fun trivia not for practicality

Comment: Ok. `=]` On topic, OP you should more specific about checking for support. Do you want to check if the `$file.click()` is supported as result of user input? Can the file input be hidden by accessible means or do you actually need `display:none`/`visibility:hidden`? These 2 factors make huge differences.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté does your jsfiddle work because you are using a button as opposed to an a:link?

Comment: @Anthony Remove the `/show` from the URL and edit it to try it out. `=]` I believe as long as it results from a click event it should work fine. Not sure about keyboard events but they should work as well.

Comment: @Anthony you can replace button with a and try: http://jsfiddle.net/XwPwu/2/

Comment: Sorry guys, been a long day.  Thanks.